# Query to get max donation from each person

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server called [Donations] that contains donations given by various people.

Its fields are:

```
FirstName,LastName,FullName,Description --VARCHARs
DateOrdered, --DATE
Donation     --MONEY
```

I wish to return all the fields in the table but I only want each persons largest donation record, not all of their donations.

Say the table contained 8 records, John Doe has 5 donation records and Jane Doe has 3.
I wish to write a query that will give me the donation record for John that was the largest donation he made and the donation record for Jane that was her largest donation.

How can I write this in SQL?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
  *
from
  donations d
where
  donation=(select max(donation) from donations where fullname=d.fullname group by fullname)
```

this assumes that fullname is your PK on this table.

Comment: this will return multiple rows if the person donated the same max amount on different dates

Comment: Yeah, I think I need to a better PK to this. This will help me though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using ranking functions:

```
DECLARE @Donations TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(128),LastName VARCHAR(128),
FullName VARCHAR(256),Description VARCHAR(1024), 
DateOrdered DATETIME, Donation DECIMAL)
INSERT @Donations VALUES 
('John', 'Doe', 'John Doe', '', '20120605', 125),
('John', 'Doe', 'John Doe', '', '20120603', 12.34),
('John', 'Doe', 'John Doe', '', '20120602', 13.59),
('John', 'Doe', 'John Doe', '', '20120609', 125),
('John', 'Doe', 'John Doe', '', '20120601', 15),
('Jane', 'Doe', 'Jane Doe', '', '20120612', 155),
('Jane', 'Doe', 'Jane Doe', '', '20120613', 152),
('Jane', 'Doe', 'Jane Doe', '', '20120612', 155)


-- Return maximum donations including duplicate donations 
-- on different and same dates
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FullName 
                ORDER BY Donation DESC) DenseRank
    FROM    @Donations
)

SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   DenseRank = 1
ORDER   BY Donation DESC, DateOrdered DESC

-- Return maximum donations including duplicate donations on same dates,
-- excluding duplicate donations on different dates
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FullName 
                ORDER BY Donation DESC, DateOrdered DESC) DenseRank
    FROM    @Donations
)

SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   DenseRank = 1
ORDER   BY Donation DESC, DateOrdered DESC

-- Return maximum donations excluding duplicate donations 
-- on same and different dates
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FullName 
                ORDER BY Donation DESC, DateOrdered DESC) RowNum
    FROM    @Donations
)

SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   RowNum = 1
ORDER   BY Donation DESC, DateOrdered DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select d1.*,(select max(d2.donation) where d2.fullname=d1.fullname group d2.fullname) from donation d1;
```